# Getting error message "Not declared in scope"

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ project and while compiling, I am receiving the error messages:

> error: `mean` was not declared in this scope
>   error: `standard_dev` was not declared in this scope

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N(0);
    char filename[100];
    double m, stdev;
    string temp;

    double next;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter name of file: ";
    cin >> filename;

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(filename);
    while (myfile >> next)
    {
        count++;
    }
    N = count;
    double* mydata;
    mydata = new double[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        myfile >> mydata[i];
    }
    m = mean(mydata, N);
    stdev = standard_dev(mydata, m, N);
    cout << "The standard deviation is:" << stdev << endl;

    myfile.close();
    delete[] mydata;
    return 0;
}

double mean(double* mydata, double N)
{
    double sum(0), m;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum += mydata[i];
    }
    m = (sum / (double) N);
    return (m);
}
double standard_dev(double* mydata, double m, int N)
{
    double* mydata2 = new double[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        mydata2[i] = pow((mydata[i] - m), 2);
    }
    double sum(0), S, X;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum += mydata2[i];
    }
    X = sum / N;
    S = sqrt(X);
    return (S);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those functions have not been seen yet when you try to use them; the compiler doesn't know what they are which leads to the error. Either move them before `main()` or prototype them, such as:

```
double mean(double * mydata, double N);
double standard_dev(double * mydata, double m, int N);
int main()
{
    ...
```

This will give the compiler its expectations for those symbols, so when it sees them in use it knows what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Any name must be defined before its using (with rare exceptions relative to template). You use name `mean` in statement

```
m =  mean(mydata, N);
```

but name `mean` is not yet defined.

Place function declarations before main

```
double mean(double *mydata, double N);
double standard_dev(double *mydata, double m, int N);

int main()
{
//...
```

Or before their usage.

```
int main()
{
   double mean(double *mydata, double N);
   double standard_dev(double *mydata, double m, int N);

   //...
   m =  mean(mydata, N);
   //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have prototypes for your functions `mean()` and `std_dev()` at the top of your file. Otherwise, they don't 'exist' in the main function. Either copy the entire functions to the space above your main function, or make prototypes for them. Good luck!